# Change JSONObject to arraylist and show in listview

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
    "Output": [
        {
            "Description": "Desc1",
            "Amount": 40,
            "TotalQuota": 40,
            "QuotaPerOne": 2
        },
        {
            "Description": "Desc2",
            "Amount": 50,
            "TotalQuota": 60,
            "QuotaPerOne": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I try to get the value of column "Description" of the above 2 items, and put in a Arraylist by the code below:

```
try{
        JSONArray output = importData.getJSONArray("Output");

        ArrayList<String>Title = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<output.length();i++) {
            String bookingInfo = output.getJSONObject(i).toString();
            bookingList.add(bookingInfo);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

But I only get the whole column of item1 and item2. My expect result is to put "Desc1","Desc2" into ArrayList Title, please help!

Comment: *But I only get the whole column of item1 and item2.* then do not use toString() but the proper method to get proper property ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

To get only `Description` from the **JSON**

```
ArrayList<String> Title = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<output.length();i++) {
  JSONObject jsonObject = output.getJSONObject(i)
  // Check if the jsonObject contains "Description Tag"
  if(jsonObject.has("Description")){
      String descrption = jsonObject.getString("Description");
      Title.add(descrption);
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to add one more thing over here: Use `Title.add()` instead of `bookingList.add()` to add description value into `Title` arrayList.

Comment: Then add to the 'title' arraylist

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using an icorrect method
use this instead, this works for me:

```
for(int i = 0;i<ja.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                            User u = new User();
                            u.userid = jo.getString("userId");//add descripton here
                            u.id = jo.getString("id");//amount and so on
                            u.title = jo.getString("title");
                            u.body = jo.getString("body");
                            list_user.add(u);
                            h.sendEmptyMessage(i);
                            Thread.sleep(300);

                        }
}
```

you just need to change it accorduing to ur json data, like you need to add booklist instead of user and so on